# Showing page sizes drop down list and refresh button on kendo grid MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

Does anyone know how to showing page sizes drop down list and refresh button on the footer kendo grid MVVM likes [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html)

Here is my view code:

```
<div id="customer-grid"
            data-role="grid"
            data-sortable="true"
            data-selectable="true"
            data-pageable="true"
            data-pagesizes="[5, 10, 20]"
            data-columns='[
            { field: "CustomerID", title: "ID", width: "75px" },
            { field: "CompanyName", title: "Company"},
            { field: "ContactName", title: "Contact" },
            { field: "ContactTitle", title: "Title" },
            { field: "Address" },
            { field: "City" },
            { field: "Region" },
            { field: "PostalCode" },
            { field: "Country" },
            { field: "Phone" },
            { field: "Fax" } ]'
            data-bind="source: customerSource">
    </div>
```

and here is my data source code:

```
var customerSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                async: false,
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },

        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: customerModel,
            data: "data",
            total: "count"
        },
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `data-pageable` as:

```
data-pageable="{ refresh: true, pageSizes: [5, 10, 20]  }"
```

Please, note that the array of page sizes is defined in `data-pageable` and not in `data-pagesizes`.

So your grid definition would be:

```
<div id="customer-grid"
        data-role="grid"
        data-sortable="true"
        data-selectable="true"
        data-pageable="{ refresh: true, pageSizes: [5, 10, 20] }"
        data-columns='[
            { field: "CustomerID", title: "ID", width: "75px" },
            { field: "CompanyName", title: "Company"},
            { field: "ContactName", title: "Contact" },
            { field: "ContactTitle", title: "Title" },
            { field: "Address" },
            { field: "City" },
            { field: "Region" },
            { field: "PostalCode" },
            { field: "Country" },
            { field: "Phone" },
            { field: "Fax" } ]'
        data-bind="source: customerSource">
</div>
```

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/9zL6J/

Comment: thanks for your quick response, and your answer is working as I expected :)